# Printing a large tree from the party package

Tags: r, tree, party

I have created a tree using the `party` package in `R`. The tree is fine, but it is very large (27 terminal nodes). Attempts to print it result in unreadable files, with oval overlapping each other.

How can I create something readable?

Can I print subsections of the tree?  E.g. a first page with the top few nodes and then subsequent pages starting at granddaughter nodes?

Any other suggestions for visualizing such a tree?

EDIT
Stephen asked for a reproducible example; that's reasonable but hard here; the interrelationships of the variables are key to there being a tree, and those are hard (at least for me!) to simulate. Also, some variables are categorical and some continuous.  But here is a version of the output from printing the tree structure in R. (I substituted V1 etc for variable names)

```
1) v1 == {AS, IT, LS, NS}; criterion = 1, statistic = 106.413
  2) v2 <= 0; criterion = 1, statistic = 37.039
    3) v1 == {NS}; criterion = 1, statistic = 34.458
      4)*  weights = 316 
    3) v1 == {AS, IT, LS}
      5) V3 <= 2; criterion = 1, statistic = 28.409
        6) V4 <= 0; criterion = 0.997, statistic = 15.053
          7) v5 == {A: Maste, B: Bache, C: Assoc}; criterion = 0.964, statistic = 15.43
            8) V6 <= 24.1068; criterion = 0.98, statistic = 11.242
              9)*  weights = 259 
            8) V6 > 24.1068
              10)*  weights = 886 
          7) v5 == {D: Plus2}
            11)*  weights = 38 
        6) V4 > 0
          12) V7 <= 0; criterion = 1, statistic = 22.142
            13)*  weights = 440 
          12) V7 > 0
            14) V8 <= 1; criterion = 0.999, statistic = 17.06
              15)*  weights = 88 
            14) V8 > 1
              16)*  weights = 59 
      5) V3 > 2
        17)*  weights = 100 
  2) v2 > 0
    18)*  weights = 41 
1) v1 == {, BM, CJ, HS}
  19) V4 <= 0; criterion = 1, statistic = 60.5
    20) V7 <= 0; criterion = 1, statistic = 41.949
      21) V9 <= 0; criterion = 0.985, statistic = 15.936
        22)*  weights = 376 
      21) V9 > 0
        23) V8 <= 1; criterion = 1, statistic = 30.046
          24) V10Wks <= 7.142857; criterion = 1, statistic = 19.078
            25) v11 <= 3.5738; criterion = 0.989, statistic = 12.966
              26)*  weights = 524 
            25) v11 > 3.5738
              27)*  weights = 853 
          24) V10Wks > 7.142857
            28)*  weights = 27 
        23) V8 > 1
          29) v12 <= 0; criterion = 1, statistic = 27.748
            30)*  weights = 38 
          29) v12 > 0
            31)*  weights = 88 
    20) V7 > 0
      32) V14 <= 0; criterion = 1, statistic = 25.564
        33) V8 <= 1; criterion = 0.98, statistic = 13.9
          34)*  weights = 115 
        33) V8 > 1
          35)*  weights = 48 
      32) V14 > 0
        36) V13 <= 2; criterion = 0.983, statistic = 11.504
          37)*  weights = 96 
        36) V13 > 2
          38)*  weights = 91 
  19) V4 > 0
    39) V8 <= 1; criterion = 1, statistic = 25.961
      40) V3 <= 0; criterion = 0.999, statistic = 17.093
        41) V14 <= 0; criterion = 0.965, statistic = 10.183
          42)*  weights = 127 
        41) V14 > 0
          43)*  weights = 480 
      40) V3 > 0
        44)*  weights = 172 
    39) V8 > 1
      45) v15 <= 0; criterion = 0.995, statistic = 14.604
        46) V9 <= 0; criterion = 0.987, statistic = 12.104
          47) v1 == {HS}; criterion = 1, statistic = 21.895
            48)*  weights = 43 
          47) v1 == {BM, CJ}
            49) v16 <= 0; criterion = 0.979, statistic = 15.049
              50)*  weights = 30 
            49) v16 > 0
              51)*  weights = 14 
        46) V9 > 0
          52)*  weights = 34 
      45) v15 > 0
        53)*  weights = 141
```

I hope that gives some idea of the structure; lots of nodes!

By default, `plot` in `party` puts each split in an ellipse and puts additional info for the terminal nodes. But that won't fit on a page.

Comment: Could you post a working example, some simulated data (using `set.seed()` for reproducibility), that will yield a reproducible tree of similar size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried increasing the image size? I outlined an example here with the partykit package, but it works the same with the party package (I used party for a while until my data set size started crashing party):

[How do I jitter the node split strings in plotting ctree output from partykit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581587/how-do-i-jitter-the-node-split-strings-in-plotting-ctree-output-from-partykit/26392523#26392523)

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be exactly what I needed.